# Changing a value in a yaml file without affecting formatting, comments etc

Tags: bash, yaml

I have a bash script that needs to set a couple of values in a yaml file.

To simplify things, let's say I want to turn:

```
foo_bar:
  name: foo-bar
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
abc_123:
  name: abc-123
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
```

into

```
foo_bar:
  name: foo-bar
  version: "1.0.0-beta.2"
abc_123:
  name: abc-123
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
```

(Notice the `2` in the first version)

I found [yq](https://pypi.org/project/yq/) to be quite effective at that:

```
yq -yi ".foo_bar.version = \"1.0.0-beta2\"" values.yaml
```

Unfortunately, when using yq, all my comments get stripped and unnecessary whitespace gets removed. But I need the file to stay exactly the same, besides the value that I want to change.

In JavaScript, I can do it as follows, but I can't use nodejs etc in my script because it's too big.

```js
const a = `
foo_bar:
  name: foo-bar
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
abc_123:
  name: abc-123
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
`
const b = a.replace(/(name:\s*foo-bar\n\s*version:\s*\")[^\"]+(\")/, (m,m1,m2)=> m1+'1.0.0-beta.2'+m2)

console.log(b)
```

Any ideas, how I could achieve the same with bash?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `sed`?

BSD `sed` (Mac O/S) would be:

```
$ cat t.yml
foo_bar:
  name: foo-bar
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
abc_123:
  name: abc-123
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
$ sed -i -e '1,/1.0.0-beta.1/s/1.0.0-beta.1/1.0.0-beta.2/' t.yml
$ cat t.yml
foo_bar:
  name: foo-bar
  version: "1.0.0-beta.2"
abc_123:
  name: abc-123
  version: "1.0.0-beta.1"
```

GNU `sed` will be different.

Comment: The version is completely dynamic and I also need to ensure to set the version of the right object (foo_bar in this case). My actual yaml file is way bigger, I just simplified it for the question.